# Define a priority queue per thread in C++ OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am parallelizing a for loop in OpenMP and I am trying to create a priority queue per thread so I can update the priority queue corresponding to the thread, so I am trying something like this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <omp.h>

void test(){

  // I need a priority queue per thread
  // std::priority_queue<int> q_per_thread;

  # pragma omp parallel for num_threads(10)
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      // push i to the queue corresponding to the thread
  }

}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data in the queue after the parallel loop?

Comment: Why a queue per thread *and* loops? Loops are for data parallelism, where you *don't* and *shouldn't* have to care about the threads that process your data. Shouldn't you be looking at *task* parallelism or agents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array of priority queues, since you are going to have multiple threads in the parallel OpenMP section:

```
 // I need a priority queue per thread
 std::vector<std::priority_queue<int>> q_per_thread(10);

 # pragma omp parallel for num_threads(10)
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    // push i to the queue corresponding to the thread
    q_per_thread[omp_get_thread_num()].push(i);
 }
```

EDIT: fixed it

Comment: It seems to me that this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42341174/2542702 is better.

Answer (score 2):

If the extent of the priority queues is only the parallel region, then you can write this code to make that explicit (and avoid building in the number of threads and the unpleasant `num_threads(10)` clause and `omp_get_thread_num()` calls) something like this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::priority_queue<int> q;
#pragma omp for 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // push i to the queue corresponding to the thread
        q.push(i);
        ... whatever else you're intending to do with the q ...
    }
 }
```